# Adding new button in tinymce wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Currently with WordPress, we have 2 buttons for Tinymce, one is "Visual" and second is "Text", I want to add another editor here "Custom Editor", and in this instance I will be adding shortcode visual things, for example replacing shortcodes with custom DIV (rollover shoring Edit button etc).. Is there any tutorial there or where can I get started with just another Tinymce to WordPress through plugin.